# Moving along circles

Tags: geometry

For each natural number 
$k$. Let 
$C_k$ denote the circle with radius 
$k$ centimetres and centre at origin. On the circle 
$C_k$
 a particle moves 
$k$ centimetres in the counter - clockwise direction. After completing its motion on 
$C_k$ the particle moves to 
$C_{k+1}$
in the radial direction. The motion of the particle continues in this manner. The particle starts at 
$(1,0)$. If the particle crosses the positive direction of the $x$-axis for the first time on the circle 
$C_n$. What is the value of $n$?

Comment: Welcome to Math SE! Here's a MathJax tutorial (https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/). MathJax helps you format your post to be more readable. In addition to this, please add your steps, where you got the problem, and where you are stuck on to help the community write the best answer for you.

Comment: Any thoughts yourself? This isn't a HW site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint. On each circle the point moves along an arc of $1$ [radian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian). Now a complete revolution is $2\pi\approx 6.28$ radians.

Comment: Thanks a lot.You helped me successfully solve it:-)

Comment: @Abcd You are welcome! If you are new here take a few minutes for a tour https://math.stackexchange.com/tour